# How to allow free download of a paid game to specific users

Tags: google-play, appstore, in-app-purchase, free-to-play

if I am a game developer, how can I allow some selected users to download it for free? The options I am aware of are the following:

- Use the built-in functionalities of play store and iTunes connect. This is not an option for me because they restricts the number of coupons I can create
- Use some deep linking framework to unlock paid features for users coming from some specific link. This could be an options, but it can means the need of too many changes to my codebase

Are there any other options than these?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you have a free game with some paid features, then it's up to you how you can give them for free to specific users. Maybe you ask for an e-mail when purchasing or something similar, and check if that e-mail is entitled for a free feature.

If you have a paid game that you want to give for free to specific users, the only way I can think of is using Store-specific features. For example on Play Store you can allow specific e-mails to get your game for free, on Steam you can generate keys that you can hand out, etc.

> Use the built-in functionalities of play store and iTunes connect. This is not an option for me because they restricts the number of coupons I can create

I'm not sure what you mean by that. I've used just the Play Store and Steam in the past, but from what I remember, the limit is high enough to not really matter. Unless you plan to give the game for free on a massive group of people, in which case it becomes tricky.